# How does the value match the column of table?(Nifi:File-->DB)

Tags: apache-nifi

issue:

i want to insert file into DB(file->DB),but the data of file does not match columns of table,so what can i do without modifying the file?

try:

Deleting the first row and Inserting a column into file to match the column of table,i made it it by using Nifi processors(GetFile--->PutDatabaseRecord) and CsvReader(set the first row as header).

need:

> Need your advice on how to use Nifi instead of modifying the file?Thx

file(txt):

```
0,1,D1400DBA,A3180602600093,20180704,145724,F,1,1,,FPPFPPPPPNNN,1,F,0,NULL

 3, R15,    5.100  ,  10.0,  10.0, 4.000000  , 0
 5, R17,    5.100  ,  10.0,  10.0, 4.000000  , 0
 7, R20,    2.200  ,  10.0,  10.0, 4.000000  , 0
```

DB(mysql):

```
id,name,    value  ,   max   ,min    ,test1 , test2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it,should use a Reader include schema about cloumn in PutDatabaseRecord.